# Call Local class within PAI Module

Tags: abap, dynpro, local-class

I have a program with 4 includes in it. One top-include (global data), one for pai-modules, one for pbo-modules and one for a local helper class.

I put the definition and implementation of my local class in the include "local helper class". Now I want to access the instance of this class inside the pai-module after an user-command with

```
lcl_class=>get_instance( )
```

I used the singleton pattern.

But when I want to activate the PAI Module, an error occurs, saying "Type lcl_class is unknown". Even when I set a variable inside my top-include, the same error occurs after I try to activate the program.

Any one know how to solve this?

Thank you and best regards

Timur

**SOLVED**

I solved this problem. Had to put the PAI-Include after the Local-Class-Helper-Include. So now its like:

```
INCLUDE Z_TEST_TOP             .    " global Data
INCLUDE Z_TEST_PBO.                 " PBO
INCLUDE Z_TEST_HELPER.              " Local Helper Class
INCLUDE Z_TEST_PAI.                 " PAI
```

Before this sequence the Include for Local Helper Class was the last one.

Answer (score 1):

It was needed just a proper sorting of the INCLUDEs in the main program.

Comment: Thank you! Solved the problem and edited my question :-)

Comment: Nice to be helpful, although my answer was not properly right. But I still think it's a bad idea to use in an Include a variable not within it. It seems pretty dangerous.

Comment: Yes you are totally right! The main thing is, if you want to use a local helper class in your program, you should put the definition into your top-include and your implementation into your local-helper-class-include. So the PAI-Module knows your helper class because the top-include comes at first... Just in case you are interested :)